# show hide div based on select option value jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I have a select list with value 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 .On select with value 0 and 1 I want to show a div, but on select with value 2,3,4,5,6,7 I want to hide that div.The code I have right now is below

**HTML**

```
<select class="rel_status">
  <option value="0">---</option>
  <option value="1">Single</option>
  <option value="2">In a relationship</option>
  <option value="3">Engaged</option>
  <option value="4">Married</option>
  <option value="5">Separated</option>
  <option value="6">Divorced</option>
  <option value="7">Widowed</option>
</select>

<div class="rel_part">                   
  <input type="text" name="part_name" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
//hide partner search form
$('.rel_part').hide(); 

//Search Relationship partner
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.rel_status').change(function(){
    if($('.rel_status').val() == '2','3','4','5','6','7') {
        $('.rel_part').show(); 
    } else {
        $('.rel_part').hide(); 
    } 
  });
});
```

The code actually works when I put

```
.val() == '2')
```

instead of

```
.val() == '2','3','4','5','6','7')
```

But then I cant show the div for other values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this `if ($.inArray($(this).val(), "2,3,4,5,6,7") == -1) {`

**Demo**

```js
//hide partner search form
$('.rel_part').hide();

//Search Relationship partner
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rel_status').change(function() {
    if ($.inArray($(this).val(), "2,3,4,5,6,7") == -1) {
      $('.rel_part').show();
    } else {
      $('.rel_part').hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="rel_status">
        <option value="0">---</option>
        <option value="1">Single</option>
        <option value="2">In a relationship</option>
        <option value="3">Engaged</option>
        <option value="4">Married</option>
        <option value="5">Separated</option>
        <option value="6">Divorced</option>
        <option value="7">Widowed</option>
    </select>


<div class="rel_part">
  <input type="text" name="part_name" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this it will works

```
$('.rel_status').change(function(){
  if($('.rel_status').val() < 2) {
    $('.rel_part').show(); 
  } else {
    $('.rel_part').hide(); 
  } 
});
```

```js
//hide partner search form
$('.rel_part').hide(); 

//Search Relationship partner
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.rel_status').change(function(){
    if($('.rel_status').val() < 2) {
      $('.rel_part').show(); 
    } else {
      $('.rel_part').hide(); 
    } 
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<select class="rel_status">
  <option value="0">---</option>
  <option value="1">Single</option>
  <option value="2">In a relationship</option>
  <option value="3">Engaged</option>
  <option value="4">Married</option>
  <option value="5">Separated</option>
  <option value="6">Divorced</option>
  <option value="7">Widowed</option>
</select>

<div class="rel_part">                   
  <input type="text" name="part_name" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a valid way of comparing one value to many others.

```
if($('.rel_status').val() == '2','3','4','5','6','7')
```

Use a logic OR Operator instead:

```
if($('.rel_status').val() == '0' || $('.rel_status').val() = '1') {
    $('.rel_part').hide(); 
} else {
    $('.rel_part').show(); 
}
```

Notice, that I switched the cases in the if clause so it's less code to write.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this is not a valid way to use `,` in Javascript, because you will end up validating `if($('.rel_status').val() == '7') {` instead.

You can change the code into this
`if($.inArray($('.rel_status').val(), ['2','3','4','5','6','7']) != -1) {`
and it should work.

Hope it helps!